# Mathematical Theorem : Combination of Gaussian Distributions

Tags: probability, summation

I have always assumed that this is fact : but are there any mathematical theorems that state: finite sums of gaussian distributions are gaussian themselves?

[image]

In the above picture, does p(x) have a gaussian distribution? Do the sums need to be linear? Can they be non-linear?

Thanks

Comment: If the last formula means you are taking convex linear combinations of guassian densities, then the resulting distribution is not gaussian in general. Note that $p(x)$ has multiple peaks in general, which cannot occur for gaussian distributions.

Comment: There is a difference between summing the distributions (actually, density functions) and considering the distribution of a sum of Gaussians (which corresponds to convolving the densities).